# Writing a csv file in R from Java using JRI

Tags: java, r, jri

Apologies in advance if this is obvious, but I can't seem to find an answer to it online. I was wondering if it is possible to write to a csv file in R from Java. For example, if I was to create normal data and write it to a csv file, I thought something like this might work:

```
Rengine re=new Rengine(args, false, new TextConsole());
re.eval("write.csv(rnorm(100,50,10), file='C:\\MyDocuments\\test.csv')")
```

Also, on a lesser note, if I create an object in R from java, is there any way to access it later? A simple example:

```
re.eval(x<-20)
re.eval(x<-x+40)
```

Comment: Please tell us what *did* happen.  That makes it much easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It says: 

Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C:\D"

The code does work in R

Comment: In that case, try  "C:\\D" to escape the escape sequence.  This is a common gotcha in bash scripting; I'm not expert enuff in Java to know where the command parsing takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Carl mentions above, this has to do with the escape character "\". I had tried "\\" as you would in java, however, R also needs to escape the escape sequence; this is where I was getting caught. In the end 6 backslashes were needed.