# Read in a csv file in R from Java (using JRI)

Tags: java, r, jri

I want to load a csv file into R from Java using JRI. For some reason when I try and do this, the program terminates and returns no error or result. Here is my Code:

```
REXP x;
x = re.eval("data<-read.csv(file='C:\\data.csv', head=TRUE, sep=',')");
x = re.eval("data<-data$VALUE");
System.out.println(x);
```

As I said, nothing happens, the program just terminates. I know there is a connection and the program is terminating due to loading the csv file, as the following code does work:

```
REXP x;
re.eval("x<-c(10,20,30,50)");
x = re.eval("x<-x+15");
double[] test = x.asDoubleArray();
System.out.println(test[0]);
re.end();
```

With the result being 25! just for additional information, I have set the environment variables, PATH, R_INCLUDE_DR, R_SHARE_DR, R_DOC_DR.

Thanks in advance,

Aran

Comment: I've debugged it and the error is:

Error: '\D' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C:\D"

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it as the correct answer for completeness.

Comment: I just posted this answer 2 days ago at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469260/writing-a-csv-file-in-r-from-java-using-jri . Aran, don't you read your own questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Carl mentioned, he did touch on the problem in another post. The problem is "\" is the escape character in both R and Java (for windows), so when passing a command from java to R you need multiple backslashes, not the normal two.

Answer (score 0):

In R studio, i write like this:

```
yangzhou<-read.csv("D:\\r-workspace\\yangzhou0715.csv")
```

And in Java , I tried many times, when I wrote like this , it worked fine:

```
rc.eval("yangzhou<-read.csv('D:\\\\\\\\r-workspace\\\\\\\\yangzhou0715.csv')");
```

NOTICE THAT: there are 8 backslashes